# Output large dataset from web service

Tags: c#, wcf, dataset, webservice-client

I wonder if anyone experienced with returning large dataset from webservice.
The dataset is around 10,000 x 60 floats.

I will be using http wcf for my webservice. 
Any ideas to approach it are welcome :)

Thanks.

Comment: 600,000 floats => 2,400,000 bytes => 2.289 MB.  Looks like we have different definitions of "large."  (There'd have to be some serious metadata overhead for this to get too out of control).

Comment: So you are saying it is not too big as i consider it? and the client and server will know how to deal with it easily?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the connections.  Do the math on the connections you plan on supporting and see if those values are kosher (it'll take about 5 minutes on a 56K modem; but only seconds on the worst high-speed connections).

Comment: There is overhead. Remember, this is WCF = XML = ASCII. Plus the XML. We possibly talk 10mb to 20mb here - large enoug hto be problem... BEFORE Zipping. Page the results.

Comment: TomTom,
Do you have best practice for paging? i'm not sure how to page a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

There's no technical reason you can't do it.

You just have to consider the amount of data that is being transfered and realize that it may take your client a while to download and deserialize the results.

If you're really worried about the amount of data going over the wire, you could use a library like Google's protocol buffers to do binary serialization (rather than the XML or JSON that you get out of the box with WCF). You can find the .NET port of Protocol Buffers at:

[protobuf-net - Project Hosting on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Comment: Thanks Justin,
From your experience would you say it is big object or this is something people are doing all the time?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the size until you try it and see if there's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not big data set. You can use web service to return such dataset without any implementation problems. You just need to set maxReceivedMessageSize and maxArrayLength on the client.

The real set of questions you should ask is:

- How many concurrent clients can use this service?
- What is expected response time?
- How often does a client call this service?
- What bandwidth is available on production server?
- What bandwidth is available on clients?

Answers to these questions show you if 2.3MB is a big data set. If you are affraid of performance and response time you should definitely plan load tests.

Comment: +1 Nice breakdown of what to look for when sizing transmissions